# How to put the result of foreach loop in an Array and get the highest value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

in this foreach loop, i put a function returning the room quantity, each $sumqty['room_qty']  has different value, my question is, i want to get the highest value of $sumqty['room_qty'], do i put it in an array? how? any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
    foreach($reservation as $res){
    $sumqty = sumqty($res['arrival'],$res['departure'],$res['room_id']);
    $sumqty['room_qty'];
    }

    $highest = ???;
?>
```

i want to display the highest value by echo $highest

Comment: Are you looking to count the actual number of rooms?

Comment: You can use `max($array)` to get the highest value from your array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an array. Provided `$sumqty['room_qty']` is a numeric value the following will work:

```
$allquantities=array();
foreach($reservation as $res){
    $sumqty = sumqty($res['arrival'],$res['departure'],$res['room_id']);
    $allquantities[]=$sumqty['room_qty'];
}

$highest = max($allquantities);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that sumqty takes an 'arrival', 'departure' and 'room id' and returns an array with key 'room_qty' mapped to some integer:

```
<?php
$highest = -1000000000; //some really, really small number
foreach ($reservation as $res) {
    $sumqty = sumqty($res['arrival'],$res['departure'],$res['room_id']);
    if ($sumqty['room_qty'] > $highest) {
        $highest = $sumqty['room_qty'];
    }
}
echo $highest;
```

The general idea is that each time you find a higher value, you replace the previously highest value with the new higher value.

No extra array is necessary to accomplish this! Solutions that use an array to solve this problem are unnecessarily complicated. (edit: "complicated" is a poor choice of words; if an extra array is used than the program is slightly less efficient)

Answer (score 0):

Get an array of all the values of `$sumqty['room_qty']`, `$room_qty[]` as in this case.

```
<?php
    $room_qty = array();
    foreach($reservation as $res){
    $sumqty = sumqty($res['arrival'],$res['departure'],$res['room_id']);
    $room_qty[] = $sumqty['room_qty'];
    }

    $highest = max($room_qty);
?>
```

Once you have the array you could use max() function to find the maximum value in the given array. Go through [this manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) you will get be clear about it.